Find the probability that the same boy does not receive both the pens.

$10$ different books and $2$ different pens are given to $3$ boys so that each gets equal number of things. Find the probability that the same boy does not receive both the pens.

My Attempt:
Number of ways of distributing $12$ objects among $3$ boys=$\frac{12!}{4!4!4!3!}\times3!$
Number of ways of distributing $10$ books among $3$ boys=$\frac{10!}{2!4!4!2!}\times3!$ ($2$ pens going to the same boy got covered here, right?)
Therefore, required probability=$1-\frac{10!4!3!}{12!2!2!}=1-\frac{6\times6}{12\times11}=\frac8{11}$
Is this correct?
As per tardigrade website, the answer is $\frac5{11}$
As per Byju's website, the answer is $\frac{10}{11}$
As per Vedantu website, the answer is $\frac8{11}$.

Your answer $\frac{8}{11}$ should be right.
Tardigrade and Vedantu agree that the total cases are $\frac{12!}{4!4!4!}$ (Byju gets wrong here), and the cases to be subtracted should have a $\{\frac{10!}{2!4!4!}\}$ factor. However, the two sites say the term in curly brackets should be multiplied by $3!$ and $3$ respectively and give different answers.
To demonstrate, we consider the three boys sitting in a circle. To count the cases to be subtracted, we always distribute the pens first and order the boys in clockwise direction, starting from the boy getting the both pens. This yields a $3$ instead of $3!$ factor of orders of boys.
Alternatively, I would say that after distributing the first pen, when distributing the second pen there will be $3$ out of $11$ slots to have the boy get two pens, so it is $\frac{8}{11}$.
Alternatively, the Mathematica code below should sample the cases directly and correctly, which agrees with the result above.
Try = 11000;
Set0 = Range[12];
Num = 0;
For[i = 1, i < Try, i++,
 Shuffle = RandomSample[Set0];
 boy1 = Shuffle[[1 ;; 4]];
 If[ContainsAll[boy1, {1, 2}] == True,
  Num = Num + 1;];
 boy2 = Shuffle[[5 ;; 8]];
 If[ContainsAll[boy2, {1, 2}] == True,
  Num = Num + 1;];
 boy3 = Shuffle[[9 ;; 12]];
 If[ContainsAll[boy3, {1, 2}] == True,
  Num = Num + 1;];
 ]
Print[Try - Num];


Each boy is to receive 4 items.
Let’s imagine the item distribution is as follows:
I am assuming that the item distribution is random.
Initially each boy has 4 empty boxes with one item to be distributed to each box.
One item at a time, an item is selected for distribution and then randomly placed into a currently empty box.
Without loss of generality, we can assume that the pens (call them pen1 and pen2) are distributed first.
After pen1 is distributed, one boy (call him John) will have a box with pen1 in it and 3 empty boxes.  The other two boys will each have 4 empty boxes.
Just before pen2 is to be distributed, there are 11 empty boxes with 3 of them belonging to John and other 8 belonging to the other two boys.
The probability that John won’t get pen2 is $\dfrac{8}{11}.$
In other words, the probability that the same boy does not receive both the pens is $\dfrac{8}{11}.$

With $P$ for pens and $B$ for books, valid /invalid distributions, each with $3$ permutations are as under:
Valid: $PB^3-PB^3-B^4: [\binom21\binom{10}3][\binom11\binom73][\binom44]\times 3 = A\; (say)$
Invalid:
$P^2B^2-B^4-B^4: [\binom22\binom{10}2[\binom84][\binom44]\times 3 = B\; (say)$
Probability $= \dfrac{A}{A+B} = \dfrac 8{11}$
